# What's the difference between TOPLEVEL_BINDING and binding?

Tags: ruby, irb

I opened `irb` and checked the value of `binding` and `TOPLEVEL_binding`:

```
2.7.0 :021 > TOPLEVEL_BINDING
 => #<Binding:0x00007fbd7d85bb18>
2.7.0 :022 > binding
 => #<Binding:0x00007fbd7c2ce908>
```

My understanding was that `TOPLEVEL_binding` and `binding` in a new `irb` session should both point to the same object: the binding object for `main`'s execution context. Why are they different?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`TOPLEVEL_BINDING` is a constant.

`binding` is a method which creates a new binding specific to the place where it is called.

```
> TOPLEVEL_BINDING #=> #<Binding:0x0000564e7226f1d0>
> TOPLEVEL_BINDING #=> #<Binding:0x0000564e7226f1d0> -- same object
> binding #=> #<Binding:0x0000564e72892aa8>
> binding #=> #<Binding:0x0000564e728907f8> -- new object
> TOPLEVEL_BINDING.source_location #=> ["<main>", 0]
> binding.source_location #=> ["(irb)", 6]
> binding == binding #=> false
> x = 2
> b = binding
> z = 4
> TOPLEVEL_BINDING.eval('x') #=> NameError
> TOPLEVEL_BINDING.eval('z') #=> NameError
> b.eval('x') #=> 2
> b.eval('z') #=> NameError
> binding.eval('x') #=> 2
> binding.eval('z') #=> 4
```